# Mysterious error when trying to include a vertical fill inside a tabular

Tags: tables, errors

I am trying to make a frontpage (for an exam), and must follow an official norm. I am using a tabular environment, but need to have some large vertical whitespace within the table filled out. I try to do that with an \vspace*{\fill}, but that makes some really weird errors, and I do not understand what is happening! The error message:

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[norsk,a4paper,12pt,twoside,pdftex]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}% we use array in place of tabularx because
%tabularx do not treat \multicolumn well enough.  Then we do have to
%measure length ourself.  We keep the package because we use  one of
%its commands
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{makecell}%used for \macecell command, allowing for
                     %linebreaks within tabular
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}% Bruker kommandoene \newgeometry og \restoregeometry  
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.0}% (1.0 is for standard spacing)

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.1cm,top=1.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.35\linewidth}
  %\includegraphics[scale=0.8,clip]{hbv}\hfill 
\end{minipage}\hfill 
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.60\linewidth}
\hfill\textsc{BOKMÅL}\\ \vfill 
{\Large\textbf{EKSAMENSFORSIDE} \\[0.5cm]   
Skriftlig eksamen med tilsyn }
\end{minipage}\thispagestyle{empty}  \\[4ex]
\setcounter{page}{0}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\Large}p{7.2truecm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\Large}p{4.7truecm}|
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\Large}p{6.1truecm}|}\firsthline
\textbf{Emnekode:} \textsf{\normalsize  G1MAT201} &
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\Large\textbf{Emnenavn:} \textsf{\normalsize Tall, tallteori,
    funksjoner og fagdidaktisk forskning} 
} \\    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\Large\textbf{Tillatte hjelpemidler
    (jfr. emnebeskrivelse):} \textsf{\normalsize  Tegne- og skrivesaker}    }
\\    \hline    
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\Large\textbf{Opplysninger om vedlegg:}
  \textsf{\normalsize   to sider sist i oppgavesettet   } }      \\      \hline   
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\Large\textbf{Merknader:}
  \makecell[tl]{{}\sffamily\normalsize  \\ Begynn hver
    oppgave på nytt ark.   \\
     Vekt (sum \textbf{100}) gitt ved hver deloppgave. \\   
     Alle svar skal begrunnes.     \\
     Alle mellomregninger skal vises. } }    \\                     \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{minipage}{\vspace*{\fill{}}}\end{minipage}}      \\      \hline  
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{ 
 \makecell[{{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\sffamily\normalsize}{p{6.0truecm}}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\sffamily\normalsize}{p{6.0truecm}}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\sffamily\normalsize}{p{6.0truecm}}}}]{%
Kryss av for type eksamenspapir                \\
Ruter   X      &   Linjer    &   Blanke   }  }            \\      \lasthline
\end{tabular}    \\[4ex]
{\centering \small \textbf{\textsc{kandidaten må selv kontrollere at
      oppgavesettet er fullstendig}}\\}
\newpage\restoregeometry   
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `\\ \vfill` is wrong `\vfill` should only be used in vertical mode not between lines of a paragraph, you should use a blank line not `\\ ` before it. You don't need to load `tabularx` if you are not using it, despite what the comment says:-)

Comment: Thanks!  But that does not solve the problem.  I get problems from the code  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{minipage}{\vspace*{\fill{}}}\end{minipage}}      \\      \hline    which tries to put vertical space between the two parts of the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
\begin{minipage}{\vspace*{\fill{}}}
```

That argument `\fill{}` should be `\fill` in the argument to `\vspace` `{}` is not legal in a length expression) but the argument is the *width* of the minipage so shoudl have a length like `3cm` it can't have a horizontal or vertical space command.

That is the cause of the error but I'm not sure I can guess the intention, so don't offer a fix.

Comment: The intention:  There is two parts of the table, which should be separated by vertical white space. If I just make that as two tables, the vlines/spacings do not line up, that is why I try to make them into one table with \vfill inside it! thank ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The natural length of `\vfill` is 0pt just as if you go `\mbox{\hfill}` you get the natural horizontal space which is 0pt, perhaps you just want `\\[1cm]` on the end of the table row?

Comment: I can try that, measuring the space myself and not leaving it to latex ...

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is my final solution as a corrected version of the minimal example. This now produces what I want:

```
\documentclass[norsk,a4paper,12pt,twoside,pdftex]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{makecell}%used for \macecell command, allowing for
                     %linebreaks within tabular
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}% Bruker kommandoene \newgeometry og \restoregeometry  
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.0}% (1.0 is for standard spacing)

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.1cm,top=1.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.35\linewidth}
  %\includegraphics[scale=0.8,clip]{hbv}\hfill 
\end{minipage}\hfill 
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.60\linewidth}
\hfill\textsc{BOKMÅL}      \vfill 
{\Large\textbf{EKSAMENSFORSIDE} \\[0.5cm]   
Skriftlig eksamen med tilsyn }
\end{minipage}\thispagestyle{empty}  \\[4ex]
\setcounter{page}{0}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\Large}p{7.2truecm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\Large}p{4.7truecm}|
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\Large}p{6.1truecm}|}\firsthline
\textbf{Emnekode:} \textsf{\normalsize  G1MAT201} &
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\Large\textbf{Emnenavn:} \textsf{\normalsize Tall, tallteori,
    funksjoner og fagdidaktisk forskning} 
} \\    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\Large\textbf{Tillatte hjelpemidler
    (jfr. emnebeskrivelse):} \textsf{\normalsize  Tegne- og skrivesaker}    }
\\    \hline    
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\Large\textbf{Opplysninger om vedlegg:}
  \textsf{\normalsize   to sider sist i oppgavesettet   } }      \\      \hline   
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\Large\textbf{Merknader:}
  \makecell[tl]{{}\sffamily\normalsize  \\ Begynn hver
    oppgave på nytt ark.   \\
     Vekt (sum \textbf{100}) gitt ved hver deloppgave. \\   
     Alle svar skal begrunnes.     \\
     Alle mellomregninger skal vises. } }    \\                     \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}
\\[10cm]      \hline  
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\sffamily\normalsize Kryss av for tpe
  eksamenspapir}    \\  
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Ruter  \textbf{\Large X} \hfill  Linjer  \hfill  Blanke }
\\     \lasthline   
\end{tabular}    \\[4ex]
{\centering \small \textbf{\textsc{kandidaten må selv kontrollere at
      oppgavesettet er fullstendig}}\\}
\newpage\restoregeometry   
\end{document}
```